# Removing everything but filename extension

Tags: linux, bash

Let's say I have a string:

```
x=file.tar.sh
```

I know how to remove everything but last n-characters. Like this (removing everything but last 3 characters:

```
${x: -3}
```

But this doesn't work for files with different suffix lengths. (len .tar != len .sh)

I would tackle this by removing everything until the last dot. I've tried this:

```
${x##.}
```

This removes the longest matching until "." but somehow it just returns the full string without removing anything?

Comment: your assignment is wrong should be this `x=file.tar.sh`

Comment: You seem to misunderstand what `${x##.}` should do. That will only remove  a single leading period, and is identical to `${x#.}` since the given pattern only matches a single literal string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
x=file.tar.sh
echo ${x##*.}
```

This will print `sh`

If you want to get `tar.sh`, then:

```
echo ${x#*.}
```

Here `*` matches any set of characters before the occurrence of `.`

Comment: Thanks, that works, but I don't understand the need for "*". Does it have to be used when using special characters?

Comment: What Jahid didn't explain was that he used **parameter expansion/substring extraction** to parse the line to remove the unwanted portions of the path. `##` starts from the left and then matches **all occurrences of pattern** `*.` (which says match everything up to the last `.`). The `*` is the wildcard for **zero or more occurrences of any character**. A single `#` matches **the first occurrence of pattern**.

Comment: Ok the only thing I really didn't get is the wildcard part. Thanks for clearing that up for me, I appreciate it.

Comment: @mythic http://www.linfo.org/wildcard.html